# Application Insights Visual Studio integration not working for Console application (WebJob)

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk, appinsights

I have a console application we deploy as a WebJob in Azure. Application Insights is working, because the telemetry is send to Azure correctly. But the "Application Insights Search" window in Visual Studio (2019) is not picking up the telemetry locally. What do I need to configure, so the application insights window will show the telemetry for the console application?

In the solution we have an MVC website and the WebJob together in the same solution. The telemetry works locally for the MVC website project, but not for the webjob project.

I have integrated Application Insights with the following code:

```
builder.ConfigureLogging((context, loggingBuilder) =>
{
  loggingBuilder.AddApplicationInsightsWebJobs(o =>
  {
    o.InstrumentationKey = instrumentationKey;
    o.EnableLiveMetrics = true;
    o.LiveMetricsInitializationDelay = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
    o.SamplingExcludedTypes = "Exception";
  });
});
```

The instrumentation key comes from the appsettings.json:

```
  "Company.Logging": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "1242189c-1192-41d9-b877-b26890bd0eef",
    "LoggingServiceUrl": "https://loggingapidev.company.com/api/logs/batch"
  }
```

We use the same configuration for the website, that works.

I did try to add the "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY" key in the appsettings.json and as an environment variable. That didn't have any effect.

Does anyone know what I can do to make this work? It would make it more intuitive for developers to work with application insights. Now I have to direct them to the portal where they can find their local telemetry.

Comment: Are you using an “Environment” value (e.g. Production vs Development)? Does it behave differently in Debug vs. Release builds? Is anything mentioning AppInsights written to the VS Output window when debugging? Have you verified that your `ConfigureLogging` callback is being invoked at all?

Comment: Thanks for you response. Just tried running with Environment=Production. The console gets a lot less chatty (no trace messages anymore), so it is picked up. But no change to the Application Insights Search window.  For Debug vs Release there is no difference at all

Comment: In the output you can see the json that is being send to Application Insights, so the logging itself in the app is working. I think that also means I know for sure that the ConfigureLogging is being called. The issue is not with application insights in the app, just that the Application Insights Search window doesn't understand it needs to "show" that telemetry.

Comment: @ErikSteinebach, something needs to confirm. 1: for the webjob, are you using webjob sdk, v2 or v3? 2:for the search window in vs, could you please show us a screenshot(it's better if you can provide a full screenshot)?

Comment: These are the referenced nuget packages:
AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection 8.0.1
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables 3.1.7
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs 3.0.18
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions 3.0.6
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage 4.0.2
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Storage 4.0.1
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting 3.1.7
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console 3.1.7
So as far as I know that is V3 correct?

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the Search window: https://ibb.co/BTJFv7s

Comment: @ErikSteinebach, a quick test, and for console project(also webjob), I can see the logs are shown in Search in Visual Studio. I attach [an screenshot](https://yy1.blob.core.windows.net/test8/insights-vs.JPG), and add some comments there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested it with console project(webjob v3), and it works fine. I can see the logs are shown in Visual Studio Application Insights Search window.

If this issue still occurs at your side, please give it a try by manually adding an **empty** `ApplicationInsights.config` file to your webjob project.

Workflow:

- Right click project: Add -> new item...
- Choose: Application Configuration File, like "JavaScript JSON Configuration File".
- Name: ApplicationInsights.config
- Remove the content of this file -> then click save. Then right right
  this file-> select Properties -> Set "Copy to Output Directory" as
  "Copy if newer"

Comment: So yes, adding the empty file actually solved the problem. Feels like a bug to me? But it is fine, I can live with it. Thank you very much

Comment: According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/configuration-with-applicationinsights-config it should be added by default, but it really doesn't. I find it baffling.